# How to remove na from ggplot scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

Is anyone able to help me with my ggplot please. I have tried multiple ways to remove the na from the plot, including na.rm = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE and placing these in different areas of the code. I have also tried using na.omit but this removes all data in the dataframe, instead of just na.

```
Birth_Sex_Plot <- ggplot(sarah_data2, aes(x=days_birth_measurement, y=hc_birth, colour= Autism)) +
  theme_classic()+ ylab("HC_Birth") + xlab("Days since measurement")

Birth_Sex_Plot + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE, fullrange = FALSE, na.rm=FALSE)
```

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you post your sample data so we can recreate this issue (i.e. using `dput(sarah_data2[100,])` for the first 100 lines (or something similar)? My sense is that `NA` is a character value, `"NA"` not a true `NA` perhaps. It is difficult to help determine the issue without sample data or the data structure.

Comment: have you tried `sarah_data2 %>% drop_na()`

Comment: If you add `scale_color_discrete(na.translate=FALSE)` that should drop the NAs from the color scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your data, this should do the job. You can `subset` your data inside the ggplot so that you remove `NA` values from your `Autism` column. You can use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

Birth_Sex_Plot <- ggplot(data=subset(sarah_data2, !is.na(Autims)), aes(x=days_birth_measurement, y=hc_birth, colour= Autism)) +
  theme_classic()+ ylab("HC_Birth") + xlab("Days since measurement")

Birth_Sex_Plot + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE, fullrange = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone's comments, the subset and !is.na(Autism) worked! thank you